# SQL: How to connect function to a string

Tags: mysql, sql, string-concatenation

Is there any way to connect function to a string?

Like this:

```
UPDATE table SET col = 'MYSTRING' . SUBSTRING_INDEX(col, ':', 2)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're using MySQL, Gordon Linoff has the answer. But your [tag:mysql] tag may have been added automatically by Stack Overflow. If you use some other RDBMS, the syntax varies. See http://blog.mclaughlinsoftware.com/2009/03/09/sql-concatenation-blues/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for `concat()`?

```
UPDATE table
    SET col = CONCAT('MYSTRING', SUBSTRING_INDEX(col, ':', 2));
```